# "Коллекция была изменена; невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления."

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetzip

Я получаю в массив строк `files` прямой путь до файла(ов) по средствам `DragDrop` на форму.

```
string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

С помощью `foreach` хочу вывести все эти файлы в `listBox`

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(file);     
}
```

Задача естественно не такая простая. Каждый `файл` представляет собой `архив с данными.`
Мне требуется `открыть` этот `архив`, для записи, и `переименовать` нужный мне файл - `сохранить.`

Что я собственно и попытался сделать с помощью библиотеки `DotNetZip`.
Я использовал за основу решения, пример из документации, вот что вышло:

```
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {                    
                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
                {
                    foreach (ZipEntry z in zip)
                    {
                        if(z.FileName == "folder/setting.ini")
                        {
                            z.FileName = "folder/config.ini";                            
                        }                     
                    }
                    zip.Save();
                }            
                listBox1.Items.Add(file);
            }
```

На выходе я получаю `Ошибку` из темы вопроса. Я понимаю что `foreach` сохраняет коллекцию и сравнивает её на каждом круге(проходе). Но для чего же в документации `DotNetZip` для изменения файла в архиве используется именно данный пример? Пока жду ответа иду пробовать через `for`, мб что-то получится.

[Примеры решений DotNetZip](http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/authentec/download/dotnetzip/examples.htm)

Comment: Обратитесь напрямую к свойству `zip.КоллекцияНейм.ToList()` если таковое есть

Comment: @Aarnihauta (ZipEntry z in zip.ToList()) - Такое обращение помогло! Спасибо большое. можете ответить, галочку гарантирую ^^

Comment: Да не, у меня в репутации число красивое 1001 ))

Comment: @Aarnihauta, xD понял.

Comment: @Aarnihauta ToArray() эффективнее, чем ToList(), всегда, кроме случаев когда массив сам по себе не подходит для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (ZipEntry z in zip.ToList()) // - Решение
{
    if(z.FileName == "folder/setting.ini")
    {
        z.FileName = "folder/config.ini";
    }                     
}
```